# Sometime getting IllegalStateException while running pipeline in dataflow runner

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, illegalstateexception

> (5d8e3f411b5a4ccb): java.lang.IllegalStateException: TimestampCombiner moved element from 2017-09-25T13:53:08.725Z to earlier time 2017-09-25T13:53:08.718Z for window [2017-09-25T13:53:08.088Z..2017-09-25T13:53:08.719Z)

What could be the expected reasons?

WindowFn Code is Simple:

```
public class BQTablePartitionWindowFn extends NonMergingWindowFn<Object, IntervalWindow> {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private IntervalWindow assignWindow(AssignContext context) {
    TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) context.element();
    String timestamp = tableRow.get(BQConstants.LOG_TIME).toString();
    String currentTime = DateUtil.getFormatedDate(new Date());
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(CommonConstants.DATE_FORMAT_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_SSS)
            .withZoneUTC();
    Instant start_point = Instant.parse(timestamp, formatter);
    Instant end_point = Instant.parse(currentTime, formatter);

    return new IntervalWindow(start_point, end_point);
};

@Override
public Coder<IntervalWindow> windowCoder() {
    return IntervalWindow.getCoder();
}

@Override
public Collection<IntervalWindow> assignWindows(AssignContext c) throws Exception {
    return Arrays.asList(assignWindow(c));
}

@Override
public boolean isCompatible(WindowFn<?, ?> other) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public WindowMappingFn<IntervalWindow> getDefaultWindowMappingFn() {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Attempted to get side input window for GlobalWindow from non-global WindowFn");
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the added detail. I've expanded my answer to discuss your `WindowFn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of `GroupByKey` is to output iterables with a timestamp that is the maximum timestamp allowed in the window. For your window, that is the timestamp `13:53:08.718Z`.

The element has the timestamp `13:53:08.725Z` which does not fall in the window from `13:53:08.088Z` to `13:53:08.719Z`.

Can you share your `WindowFn` as well as any `ParDo` you have that adjusts the timestamps?

**UPDATE:** Thanks for sharing your `WindowFn`. There are a couple things about it that are going to cause you problems.

**1. The start time of the assigned window is not based on the element's timestamp.**

You extract a column of the element and assign the window according to the value of `context.element().get(BQConstants.LOG_TIME)` (ignoring casts and parsing). From your error message, it seems that this is not the actual value of `context.timestamp()`, which is the event time timestamp of the element.

Instead, you should write your `WindowFn` to use `context.timestamp()`. You can make sure the timestamp is what you want in different ways based on whether your data is bounded:

- If your data is bounded, you can use `WithTimestamps` to assign timestamps by extracting that field.
- If your data is unbounded, the source needs to know more so it can manage the watermark, so the configuration depends on the source. As an example, `PubsubIO` reads timestamps from an attribute you can specify.

**2. The end time of the assigned window is based on the system date**

A couple issues:

- The end time is rounded down and may precede the start time, resulting in an invalid window.
- The end time is nondeterministic. The general expectation in Beam is that you'll deterministically assign a window based primarily on the element's timestamp (which must fall before the end of the window) and secondarily on the element itself. Assigning a nondeterministic window such as this probably has unforeseen drawbacks. One known issue is that your results are not reproducible, which could be trouble if you need to fix a data processing bug or run experiments on archived data. It depends on your use-case, but you might consider something more future-proof.

What is the goal here? Are you setting this up just to extract the endpoint for dynamic destinations? If so, I would suggest partitioning your data on when it happened, rather than on when it was processed.

Comment: Thanks! I've expanded my answer correspondingly.

Comment: Thanks for explaination.
I can make changes to avoid taking system time.-----------------------
And Yes, I am setting this up just to extract the endpoint for dynamic destinations. I need to set partion like according to logtime.